# How to change the color of a active button only in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

there are four buttons how to change the color of the active one being press and change it back to normal if the other button is pressed

i tried this

```
state = { active: styles.btn };

 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>


          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: styles.btnActive })}}
              style={this.state.active}>
              <Text> town </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: styles.btnActive })}}
              style={this.state.active}>
              <Text> hill </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: styles.btnActive })}}
              style={this.state.active}>
              <Text> street </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: styles.btnActive })}}
              style={this.state.active}>
              <Text> road </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

      </View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  btn: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    borderColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  btnActive: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },

});
```

but instead all the buttons color are changing when one button is press

Comment: Have you tried to give the different buttons a unique id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In React, whenever you do a `this.setState()` call the component get re-rendered. You buttons are looking to `this.state.active` for their styles, so whenever one button is pressed, the your `this.state.active` is getting updated to the btnActive styles you are passing it. I would recommend that you give each button an index so that you can distiguish between the buttons more easily.

Fair warning the code below is pretty static. If you need to make this more dynamic (say you want to generate buttons based on a list or something) you'd have to use `map` or a `for` loop, but the indexing idea would remain the same.

```
state = { active: null };

 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>

   <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
     <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: 0 })}}
       style={this.state.active === 0 ? style.btnActive : style.btn }>
         <Text> town </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>

   <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
     <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: 1 })}}
       style={this.state.active === 1 ? style.btnActive : style.btn }>
         <Text> town </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>

   <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
     <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: 2 })}}
       style={this.state.active === 2 ? style.btnActive : style.btn }>
         <Text> town </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>

   <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
     <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => {this.setState({ active: 3 })}}
       style={this.state.active === 3 ? style.btnActive : style.btn }>
         <Text> town </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>

 </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your code is using the `state.active` style for every button. What I'd do is store the active button index, or key, in state and then switch on that state to decide which style to use.

Life example: https://snack.expo.io/B1mPipDwr

```
     state = {activeIndex: 0};

     <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>
          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ activeIndex: 0 })}}
              style={this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? styles.btnActive : styles.btn}>
              <Text> town </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ activeIndex: 1 })}}
              style={this.state.activeIndex === 1 ? styles.btnActive : styles.btn}>
              <Text> hill </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ activeIndex: 2 })}}
              style={this.state.activeIndex === 2 ? styles.btnActive : styles.btn}>              
              <Text> street </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({ activeIndex: 3 })}}
                style={this.state.activeIndex === 3 ? styles.btnActive : styles.btn}>
              <Text> road </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btn: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    borderColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  btnActive: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderColor: '#dc00ff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  }
});
```