# Vue.js - conditionally assign a CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-native

In a VueNative project, which is using NativeBase as a component library (thus the tags prefixed with `nb-`), I have the following code.  This is in the `<template>` tags and is part of the footer.vue file which contains navigation buttons.  This logic is working fine to change the color of the tab (button) when the user presses it and it becomes active.

```
<nb-button :active="tab2" :onPress="toggleTab2" :style="{ backgroundColor: (activeTab == 'tab2') ? 'rgb(117, 110, 116)' : 'rgb(82, 74, 81)' }">
  <nb-text class="text">Instructions</nb-text>
</nb-button>
```

I'd like to replace `:style` with `:class` so all of the `nb-button` tags in the file refer to class names rather than hard coded background colors in each tag.  Here is what I've tried -
in the `<template>` tags:

```
<nb-button :active="tab2" :onPress="toggleTab2" :class="{ (activeTab == 'tab2') ? "active" : "inactive" }">
  <nb-text class="text">Instructions</nb-text>
</nb-button>
```

in the `<style>` tags:

```
.inactive {
  background-color: rgb(82, 74, 81);
}
.active {
  background-color: rgb(117, 110, 116);
}
```

However, in the code editor a red squiggly line is showing under the `:class` line which says "'v-bind' directives require an attribute value".  How can this be modified to work?

**Edit**
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084874/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-active-button-only-in-react-native) post I have also tried the following:

```
<nb-button :active="tab2" :onPress="toggleTab2" :style="(activeTab == 'tab2') ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
```

But it acts like it ignores the class names.  When the user chooses tab2, the default active color is displayed rather than the color specified in the `active` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not escaping the `""` inside `:class="{ (activeTab == 'tab2') ? "active" : "inactive" }"` so should replace `"` by `'` and change the syntax based on [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax):

```
:class="{ active: (activeTab == 'tab2'), inactive: (activeTab !== 'tab2')}"
```

Comment: I made the recommended change; however, it's still displaying the red squiggly line with the message `'v-bind' directives require an attribute value`.

Comment: try this `:class="(activeTab == 'tab2') ? 'active' : 'inactive'"`

Comment: OK, I tried that.  There is no more red squiggly line or error message in the editor but it's not recognizing the active class.  Instead, it is displaying the default active color.

Comment: what about `:class="{  'active' : '(activeTab == 'tab2'),'inactive' :(activeTab !== 'tab2')}"` based on [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Comment: YES!  With a slight syntax change, `:class="{ active: (activeTab == 'tab2'), inactive: (activeTab !== 'tab2')}"`, it works!  Your persistence is much appreciated.